# Limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} {(1+4x)^\frac {1}{\ln x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} {(1+4x)^\frac {1}{\ln x}}$$
as  $x \to \infty$, $\ln(x)  \to \infty$ too.

So $\frac {1}{\ln x}  \to 0$ and the limit will be 1.
But when I graph it it's different!
Why?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x) \to 0$ does not imply that $f(x)^{g(x) } \to 1$. The limit depends the behavior of $f(x)$ as $ x \to \infty$.

$(1+4x)^{1/ \log x}=e^{\frac {\log (1+4x)} {\log x}} \to e^{1}=e$ by L'Hospital's Rule. We can avoid L'Hospital's Rule also:

$x \leq 1+4x \leq 5x$ for $x >1$. Taking logarithms , dividing by $\ln x$ and taking the limit gives the limit.

Comment: Don't you get $e^{1/4}$?

Comment: @ChrisCuster No, it is $e$. The derivative of $\log (1+4x)$ is $\frac 4 {1+4x}$ and limit of $\frac {4x} {1+4x}$ is $1$.

Comment: Oops.  Forgot the chain rule.

Comment: We can also get it without L'Hôpital's rule: $\ln(1+4x)=\ln x+\ln 4+\ln(1+1/(4x))\approx\ln x+\ln 4+1/(4x)\sim\ln x$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, using $x \leq 1+4x \leq 5x$ for $x >1$, takinglogarithms , dividing by $\ln x$ and taking the limit is yet another way.